# Discover DynamicResource bindings within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, dynamicresource

Is it possible to discover all dynamic resources within a datatemplate - either within the datatemplate itself, or after it was applied to some ContentPresenter?

My idea was to make some sort of property editor to edit the appearance of wpf objects (maybe dynamically created using XamlReader) and show - for a certain object, only the resource entries used inside the corresponding DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now, I have not found a "clean" way to get the dynamic resource using framework methods.

However, one possibility is to search the DataTemplate using reflection. The dynamic resources are stored inside structs of type `System.Windows.ChildValueLookup` where the LookupType is "Resource". I have written a helper class to enumerate the resources:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace DashboardTest
{
    public struct ResourceInfo
    {
        public ResourceInfo(string resourceKey, DependencyProperty property)
            : this()
        {
            ResourceKey = resourceKey;
            Property = property;
        }

        public string ResourceKey { get; private set; }
        public DependencyProperty Property { get; set; }
    }

    public static class DataTemplateHelper
    {
        private static readonly Type ChildValueLookupType = GetType("System.Windows.ChildValueLookup");
        private static readonly FieldInfo LookupTypeField = ChildValueLookupType.GetField("LookupType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        private static readonly FieldInfo ValueField = ChildValueLookupType.GetField("Value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        private static readonly FieldInfo PropertyField = ChildValueLookupType.GetField("Property", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        private static readonly object LookupTypeResource = Enum.Parse(LookupTypeField.FieldType, "Resource");

        public static List<ResourceInfo> FindDynamicResources(DataTemplate template)
        {
            var recordField = typeof(DataTemplate).GetField("ChildRecordFromChildIndex", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            Debug.Assert(recordField != null);

            var values = EnumerateObjects(recordField.GetValue(template)).Where(IsDynamicResource).Select(ToResourceInfo).ToList();
            return values;
        }

        private static ResourceInfo ToResourceInfo(object lookup)
        {
            return new ResourceInfo((string)ValueField.GetValue(lookup), (DependencyProperty)PropertyField.GetValue(lookup));
        }

        private static Type GetType(string typeName)
        {
            foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
                if (type != null)
                    return type;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static bool IsDynamicResource(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != ChildValueLookupType) return false;
            return LookupTypeResource.Equals(LookupTypeField.GetValue(obj));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<object> EnumerateObjects(object obj)
        {
            var visited = new HashSet<object>();
            EnumerateObjectsInternal(obj, visited, 20);
            return visited;
        }

        private static void EnumerateObjectsInternal(object obj, HashSet<object> visited, int maxDepth)
        {
            if (obj == null || maxDepth <= 0) return;
            var type = obj.GetType();

            if (obj is Type || obj is string || obj is DateTime || type.IsPrimitive
                || type.IsEnum || visited.Add(obj) == false) return;

            var array = obj as Array;
            if (array != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in array)
                {
                    EnumerateObjectsInternal(item, visited, maxDepth - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var field in GetAllFields(type))
                {
                    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
                    EnumerateObjectsInternal(fieldValue, visited, maxDepth - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type type)
        {
            const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

            if (type == typeof(object) || type.BaseType == typeof(object))
            {
                return type.GetFields(bindingFlags);
            }
            else
            {
                var fieldInfoList = new List<FieldInfo>();

                var currentType = type;
                while (currentType != typeof(object))
                {
                    fieldInfoList.AddRange(currentType.GetFields(bindingFlags));
                    currentType = currentType.BaseType;
                }
                return fieldInfoList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) utility. You can look at the source code and see how you can view the style/template of any object and change its appearance.

Comment: Snoop shows me as value source only "ParentTemplate", which is the result of DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(..). However, I don't see a way to get the DynamicResourceExtension attached to the property...